# IBMMobileFirst Application Center

Tags: installation, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to install IBM Mobile First Application Center. How can I install this with my developer kit. I have the Mobile First Developer kit 8.0 on my system. I tried installing IBM installation Manager 1.8.5 but i did'nt get any option of installing application center there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install Application Center with the MobileFirst Foundation development kit.

Comment: Can't we install Application Center without moving to production?

Comment: Not as part of the developer kit.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Application Center using MobileFirst server image which can be downloaded by IBM Passport Advantage or IBM Software Access Catalog.